# Update photo in AAD with React and MS graph (404 not found)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application, in which I want to update my photo in AAD. Currently, my user have access to all scopes, including `"User.ReadWrite.All"` which as far as I understand is the scope needed to update an image in AAD with MS graph

Currently, I'm taking my image from the input and transform it to an UTF-8 string:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = () => {
    //Here I make a call to my API method to PUT the image
}
reader.readAsText(image, 'UTF-8')
```

In my API call, I'm getting the token needed for my scope which I append to the header along with my contenttype.

```
export const setProfileImage = async (file) => {
    const accessToken = await getToken("User.ReadWrite.All");
    const headers = new Headers();
    const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;
    headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
    headers.append("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
    const options = {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: headers,
        body: file
    };

    return fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value", options)
}
```

The response is 404 not found.

I've tried multiple things, for example if I change my link to and add my user-id:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/MY_ID/photo/$value
```

I get a 400 bad request response.

Moreover, I tried to do the following:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = () => {
    //Here I make a call to my API method to PUT the image
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(image)
```

Nothing really changes, I still get either 404 (For /me/) and 400 (for /MY_ID/)

The image I'm trying to upload is a few kbs, so I'm sure it's not the image causing problems

Comment: Could you put the logic of how you are actually processing the image upload? May synthesize the logic into one file. Added an answer with a full code I have tested and works fine, Also you can explain how you are getting the access token.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a few lines from your code to update the photo.

```
<input type="file" onchange="readFile(this)">
<script>
  function readFile(input) {
    let file = input.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(file);
    reader.onload = function () {
        console.log(reader.result);
        const headers = new  Headers()
        const bearer = `Bearer ${access_token}`;
        headers.append("Authorization", bearer);
        const options = { method: "PUT", headers: headers, body: file };

        fetch("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value", options)
        .then(function (o) {
            console.log(o)
        })
    };

  }
```

If this does not work for you as is then probably the issue is with your access token or tenant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Danstan - I have looked at your code and have a few questions: 

You removed the content-type, is there a specific reason why? You also passed the image directly to the body, without actually using the FileReader result. (Is that correct?) 

Anyway, I tried passing the image from my input directly, as you have done. Also removed the content-type header. Still issues though. (404 not found) Anyway, my token is correct, I can use the same token for getting userdata and userimage from graph.. In case its an issue with my tenant, where should I look then?